# How to uninstall pow (node) on mac osx

Tags: macos, pow

How to uninstall pow (http://pow.cx/) on mac osx? I frequently encounter the firewall warning of Norton due to an Unix Executable File called "node" It seems to be related to pow. 
[image]

I tried to uninstall this with command "$ curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh" in terminal, which was on the [uninstall manual](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_1.2) of pow website. But it showed as below.
Please help me with this.
[image]

Comment: For future reference, when something online shows you a `$` at the beginning of the command string, it usually refers to the $ which is in your terminal; you do not include it in the command you type. This messed me up a lot when I first learned Mac Terminal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please run this command

```
curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh
```

You are missing `uninstall.sh` in your terminal command(from your screen shot)

Comment: Thanks! I shot the wrong screen. It didn't work with "$ curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh", but your command can uninstall. Thanks!